# Firebase Database Real-time clock to learn

Tags: android, firebase

How to find out the Real Geographical Time, as in my application I want to attach the real time with my application.

So that if the user changes the time in his device then I should get only the real prevailing time - NOT THE DEVICE TIME

My question is much confusing but try to understand in a simple language -

I dont want DEVICE TIME, I want REAL PREVAILING TIME at any instant

Does Firebase offer a service to answer this question?

Comment: Please ask your own question. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` it return the current timestamp (time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) by the Firebase Database servers. check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue)

Comment: This answer got me through. Many people may not like my question. But this is not without the chat cycle.